# Overriding Iterator Signature

Tags: typescript

I want to create a wrapper on Array object to handle two dimensional arrays easier. Everything is fine but I also want to overwrite the `Symbol.iterator` to simplify the nested loops you have to do with the 2D Arrays.

I want to be able to loop the arrays like this basically

```js
const m = new Matrix([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
]);

for (let { c, r, value } = m) {
   console.log(`Column: %s, Row: %s, Value: %s`, c, r, value);
}
```

I've written the code for this and it works. However typescript complains about he iterator signature because it doesn't match with what the Array supposed to have.

Here is my code

```js
class Matrix<T=number> extends Array<Array<T>> {

    // Other methods...

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let r = 0; r < this.length; r++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < this[r].length; c++) {
                yield { c, r, value: this[r][c] as T };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Typescript is complaining that `Type '() => IterableIterator<[number, number, T]>' is not assignable to type '() => IterableIterator<T[]>'.` [You can see it live here](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyYBcBOBLAHgHgCoF4B2ArgLYBGApkgHzRloJl4AmMAgkkmAJ4ZsfdaVqAbwBQ0cdGAB7PBGQFgCKUgAUjRGABc0LAG0Augeg5oBgJTRRE69AgEADhRVmA3CLE3xAei-QAYiggINAA5igAbgzQ6ghg0ErQRIioaG6e4gBmytAqIGQI0EjG0AAMLoXQGNEaAHR5eCEIABblSADUbRZW6dbNKBC6SPrFBmk9EllFufmSOGWSldWxg-p1DI0tkh1dHuM2fQNDusDDJjFgK8f6Y3sAvrs299b3Dz7QAPLNFNBNZCCORSI+SaUmYNXB7msACpdABlTikKQgGooegcJRDZyWB7WSY5PIFIomeZFKoHNYNZqtbbYvaZbLTArAYrzZlkpr9FYUjblYA07p0iScFB-RiWSQAGkKUvCYBABDI2gOlxO0EgOmgtxu4ye6V14nuL2ksgKRGKeDIAHc4Ml0CpdB5dABGKUAJilAGZ9BLHQAWKUAVilADZvY6AOxSgAcUoAnGH9K53HjGeLgFKkDK5QrNdApBlEjsJMaIEiyHUpCEVAADADCSOIeG0AFIIFKAEpSS0ttvQABq2cV0Fb1al6el0Fl8rISduQA)

**My Question is: How can I write this code without Typescript complaining? I can stop the compiler by turning values to `Any` but then I lose all advantages of using Typescript in that case.**

Comment: You're saying both that `Matrix<T>` *is* a type of `Array<Array<T>>`, and that it is *not* an `Array<Array<T>>`.  If I do `for (let x of m) {}`, and `m` is assignable to `Array<Array<T>>`, then `x` must be `Array<T>`.  If `[number, number, T]` comes out instead, something is wrong.  I think you'll need to decide whether `Matrix<T>` should be an `Array<Array<T>>` or an `IterableIterator<[number, number, T]>`.  It can't be both.

Comment: Would it be okay if you didn't override the iterator signature and instead provide a differently named method like `unroll()` that did the same thing?  Then you could do `for (let x of m.unroll()) {}` to get row/column/value triplets.

Comment: I thought about `unroll()` just like the `entries()` and it's probably what I should do anyways. but I was wondering if there is actually a way to override this signature somehow. I can modify the behaviour maybe I should be able to express my modification too.

Comment: Like, here is my custom Matrix object, it works just like an `Array` but differs in these situations kinda way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a major headache to try to do what you're asking, as it goes against the spirit of the type system.  There is an idea called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which says that `A extends B` means that you should be allowed to use an instance of `A` anywhere an instance of `B` is expected.  Or, to put it another way, every instance of `A` *is also* an instance of `B`.

By saying that `Matrix<T> extends Array<Array<T>>`, you are claiming that a `Matrix<T>` *is* an `Array<Array<T>>`.  But if I iterate over an `Array<Array<T>>` in a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), I expect to be looping through `Array<T>` elements.  That's part of the interface contract of `Array<Array<T>>`.  If elements of type  `[number, number, T]` come out instead, something has gone wrong: a `Matrix<T>` is *not* an `Array<Array<T>>`.  The Liskov Substitution Principle has been violated.

The easy and recommended way to deal with this is to make `Matrix<T> extends Array<Array<T>>` true by leaving the iterator method alone, and just add an `unroll()` method to `Matrix<T>` which produces the desired iterator.  This added method doesn't break the substitution principle because "not having an `unroll()` method" isn't part of the `Array<Array<T>>` contract.

Something like this:

```
class Matrix<T> extends Array<Array<T>> {
  constructor(data: T[][] = []) {
    super();

    // Fill given data to matrix;
    for (let r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
      this[r] = [];
      for (let c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++) {
        this[r][c] = data[r][c];
      }
    }
  }

  *unroll(): IterableIterator<[number, number, T]> {
    for (let r = 0; r < this.length; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < this[r].length; c++) {
        yield [c, r, this[r][c]];
      }
    }  
  }

}

const m = new Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]);

for (let [c, r, value] of m.unroll()) {
  console.log(`Column: %s, Row: %s, Value: %s`, c, r, value);
}
```

---

But if you really wanted to override the iterator with your custom implementation, could you do it?   Yeah, I guess.  You can't break the `Array<Array<T>>` contract, so you'll have to write a new one.  You can try to use some type manipulation like [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) types to express "an `Array<Array<T>>` but without a defined iterator method", and then [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the `Array` constructor is also a constructor for that type of thing, and then extend *that*:

```
type _SortOfArray<T> = Pick<
  Array<Array<T>>,
  Exclude<keyof Array<any>, keyof IterableIterator<any>>
>;
interface SortOfArray<T> extends _SortOfArray<T> {}
interface SortOfArrayConstructor {
  new <T>(): SortOfArray<T>;
}
const SortOfArray = Array as SortOfArrayConstructor;

class Matrix<T> extends SortOfArray<T> {
  constructor(data: T[][] = []) {
    super();

    // Fill given data to matrix;
    for (let r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
      this[r] = [];
      for (let c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++) {
        this[r][c] = data[r][c];
      }
    }
  }

  // Other helper methods...
  *[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[number, number, T]> {
    for (let r = 0; r < this.length; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < this[r].length; c++) {
        yield [c, r, this[r][c]];
      }
    }
  }
}

const m = new Matrix([['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]);

for (let [c, r, value] of m) {
  // c is a number, r is a number, value is a string
  console.log(`Column: %s, Row: %s, Value: %s`, c, r, value);
}
```

That all works, hooray?  Well, not quite:

```
const filteredM = m.filter(row => row[0]!=='4'); 
// filteredM is a string[][] at compile time, but Matrix<string> at runtime!

for (let hmm of filteredM) {
    // compiler thinks hmm[0] is a string, but it's really a number
    console.log(hmm[0].toUpperCase()); // no compiler error, runtime error!!
}
```

See, the way `Array` extension works, methods that return new arrays actually return the extended version of the array by default (it's called the [species](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@species) of the array).  And, if a `Matrix<T>` were really an `Array<Array<T>>`, this subspecies substitution would be fine.  But we changed it to something else, so now all of the methods of `Matrix<T>` that return new arrays are typed all wrong.

In fact, to get it "right" we would have to completely write out the new contract manually:

```
interface SortOfArray<T> {
    [n: number]: Array<T>;
    length: number;
    toString(): string;
    toLocaleString(): string;
    pop(): T[] | undefined;
    push(...items: T[][]): number;
    concat(...items: ConcatArray<T[]>[]): SortOfArray<T>;
    concat(...items: (T[] | ConcatArray<T[]>)[]): SortOfArray<T>;
    join(separator?: string): string;
    reverse(): SortOfArray<T>;
    shift(): T[] | undefined;
    slice(start?: number, end?: number): SortOfArray<T>[];
    sort(compareFn?: (a: T[], b: T[]) => number): this;
    splice(start: number, deleteCount?: number): SortOfArray<T>;
    splice(start: number, deleteCount: number, ...items: T[]): SortOfArray<T>;
    // ... and on and on and on ...
```

Ugh, I can't even tell if I got that right or made some mistakes.  It's really not feeling worth it to me.  Not to mention that plenty of things that expect an `Array<Array<T>>` will start to make compiler errors if you hand it a `Matrix<T>`.

Of course you can only write out the methods and properties you care about, but it still feels like quite a slog to me, for something of questionable benefit.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck.

Comment: Awesome response. Thank you very much for detailed explanation and actually entertain my curiosity here. What you said about `Matrix` and `Array<Array<T>>` should be interchangeable makes perfect sense to me now. Matrix wrapper would add some helper methods but I should still be able to use this array with lodash or similar tools without breaking existing functionality. Thanks!